# Visual Studio Apache Cordova Error - No Android Version Supplied

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I am setting up VS Community 2015 using apache cordova for the first time and I have run into an issue when I try to run the program.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: CordovaDemo, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.7 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.4
1>  ------ Package not currently installed globally.
1>  ------ Installing globally from source package. This could take a few minutes...
1>  npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.12.7","npm":"2.11.3"})
1>  npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.6.2: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.7","npm":"2.11.3"})
1>  > edge@0.10.1 install C:\Users\bentley_n\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\edge
1>  > node tools/install.js
1>  Success: platform check for edge.js: node.js ia32 v0.12.7
1>  npm WARN installMany normalize-package-data was bundled with npm@1.3.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
1>  C:\Users\bentley_n\AppData\Roaming\npm\vs-tac-cli -> C:\Users\bentley_n\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\vs-tac-cli.cmd
1>  vs-tac@1.0.4 C:\Users\bentley_n\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac
1>  ├── rimraf@2.2.6
1>  ├── ncp@0.5.1
1>  ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
1>  ├── q@1.0.1
1>  ├── semver@2.3.1
1>  ├── adm-zip@0.4.4
1>  ├── tar@0.1.20 (inherits@2.0.1, block-stream@0.0.8)
1>  ├── fstream@0.1.28 (inherits@2.0.1, graceful-fs@3.0.8)
1>  ├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10)
1>  ├── elementtree@0.1.6 (sax@0.3.5)
1>  ├── request@2.36.0 (forever-agent@0.5.2, qs@0.6.6, oauth-sign@0.3.0, tunnel-agent@0.4.1, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, aws-sign2@0.5.0, mime@1.2.11, node-uuid@1.4.3, tough-cookie@2.0.0, form-data@0.1.4, hawk@1.0.0, http-signature@0.10.1)
1>  ├── ripple-emulator@0.9.30 (connect-xcors@0.5.2, open@0.0.3, colors@0.6.0-1, accounting@0.4.1, moment@1.7.2, request@2.12.0, express@3.1.0)
1>  ├── edge@0.10.1 (edge-cs@0.2.7, nan@1.9.0)
1>  └── plugman@0.22.4 (q@0.9.7, underscore@1.4.4, nopt@1.0.10, rc@0.3.0, cordova-lib@0.21.6, npm@1.3.4)
1>  ------ npm install of vs-tac@1.0.4 from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac completed.
1>  ------ Installing Cordova tools cordova@5.1.1 for project from npm. This could take a few minutes...
1>  npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.12.7","npm":"2.11.3"})
1>  npm WARN engine cordova-js@4.0.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.7","npm":"2.11.3"})
1>  npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.7","npm":"2.11.3"})
1>  npm WARN installMany normalize-package-data was bundled with npm@1.3.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
1>  cordova@5.1.1 node_modules\cordova
1>  ├── q@1.0.1
1>  ├── underscore@1.7.0
1>  ├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.7)
1>  └── cordova-lib@5.1.1 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, mime@1.2.11, unorm@1.3.3, semver@2.1.0, dep-graph@1.1.0, rc@0.5.2, shelljs@0.3.0, through2@0.6.3, npmconf@0.1.16, xcode@0.6.7, elementtree@0.1.6, init-package-json@1.8.0, d8@0.4.4, request@2.47.0, tar@1.0.2, cordova-registry-mapper@1.1.10, glob@4.0.6, cordova-app-hello-world@3.9.0, plist@1.1.0, cordova-js@4.0.0, npm@1.3.4)
1>  ------ npm install of cordova@5.1.1 from npm completed.
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: C:\Users\bentley_n\Desktop\Random Projects\CordovaDemo\CordovaDemo\bld\Android\Debug
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: C:\Users\bentley_n\Desktop\Random Projects\CordovaDemo\CordovaDemo\bin\Android\Debug
1>  ------    buildCommand: prepare
1>  ------    platform: Android
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: android
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: CordovaDemo
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\Users\bentley_n\Desktop\Random Projects\CordovaDemo\CordovaDemo
1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\bentley_n\AppData\Roaming\npm
1>  ------    language: en-US
1>  ------    changeList.changedFilesIos: bower.json,res\icons\android\icon-72-hdpi.png,res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-landscape.png,merges\android\scripts\android2.3-jscompat.js,merges\windows\scripts\winstore-jscompat.js,res\icons\ios\icon-60.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png,res\icons\windows\StoreLogo.scale-100.png,www\scripts\index.js,res\icons\android\icon-48-mdpi.png,res\icons\ios\icon-72.png,res\icons\ios\icon-76.png,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png,res\icons\windows\Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png,merges\android\scripts\platformOverrides.js,res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-portrait.png,www\css\index.css,res\icons\windows\StoreLogo.scale-240.png,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-landscape.png,res\icons\ios\icon-60-3x.png,res\screens\wp8\SplashScreenImage.jpg,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-568h-2x.png,res\icons\windows\Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png,package.json,res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-landscape.png,res\icons\windows\Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png,res\icons\windows\Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png,res\icons\ios\icon-72-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-76-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-small.png,res\icons\windows\Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png,build.json,res\icons\wp8\Background.png,www\index.html,res\icons\ios\icon-40.png,res\icons\ios\icon-60-2x.png,res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-portrait.png,res\native\android\ant.properties,res\icons\windows\Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png,www\scripts\platformOverrides.js,taco.json,res\icons\windows\Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png,res\icons\android\icon-36-ldpi.png,merges\windows\scripts\platformOverrides.js,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait.png,Project_Readme.html,res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-portrait.png,res\icons\ios\icon-50-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-57-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-50.png,res\icons\ios\icon-57.png,res\icons\ios\icon-small-2x.png,res\icons\windows\Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png,res\screens\windows\SplashScreen.scale-240.png,res\icons\android\icon-96-xhdpi.png,res\icons\wp8\ApplicationIcon.png,res\icons\ios\icon-40-2x.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png,res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-landscape.png,res\screens\windows\SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png,res\screens\windows\SplashScreen.scale-100.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-portrait.png,res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-landscape.png,res\icons\windows\Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png,res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-portrait.png,config.xml
1>  ------    changeList.deletedFilesIos:
1>  ------    changeList.addedPluginsIos:
1>  ------    changeList.deletedPluginsIos:
1>  ------    changeList.addedPlugins:
1>  ------    changeList.deletedPlugins:
1>  ------ Adding platform: android
1>  No version supplied. Retrieving version from config.xml...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Below is what I have in my config.xml.  I am not sure what is meant by version code.
[image]

And these are the android SDKs I downloaded

[image]

Any feedback as to why I am experiencing this error would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Could you run the dependency checker and verify that you have everything installed that Cordova expects you to have?

Go to tools -> Options -> Tools for Apache Cordova and click "Run Dependency Checker" Then, install anything that it says you're missing.

Comment: Hi, I ran the dependency checker and it came back with all good.  Nothing seems to be missing.

Comment: I checked with the team and we think it's possible you're unable to install the npm android platform package, possibly because you're behind a proxy server. If that's true, please check this for a workaround: https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/blob/master/known-issues/known-issues-npm.md Our next tools update will do a better job of surfacing this error.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I ran those commands, I am behind a proxy.  However the issue is still the same.  I then proceeded to re-installing VS 2015 Community along with all the tools, and again, the error is the same.  I will try installing it at my home laptop to see if it really is the proxy.  Are there any other programs that require proxy credentials to be set up for?